# How to remove specific elements in nested lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested

Let's say I got the following array:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 1],
         [4, 5, 6, 4],
         [7, 8, 9, 7], 
         [7, 8, 9, 7]]
```

I want to remove the first and last list in the array and than the first and last element of the middle lists (return should basically be: `[[5, 6], [8, 9]]`).

I tried the following:

```
array.remove(array[0])
array.remove(array[-1])
for i in array:
     array.remove(i[0])
     array.remove(i[-1])
```

But I always get `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to achive this is to slice the `array` list using *list comprehension* expression like:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 1],
         [4, 5, 6, 4],
         [7, 8, 9, 7],
         [7, 8, 9, 7]]

array = [a[1:-1]for a in array[1:-1]]
```

Final value hold by `array` will be:

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

---

Here `array[1:-1]` returns the list skipping the first and last element from the `array` list

Comment: Keep in mind that a list comprehension creates a new list instead of mutating the original as in OP's case

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the items from the sublist, not the parent list:

```
for i in array:
    i.remove(i[0])
    i.remove(i[-1])
```

You can also remove both items in one line using `del`:

```
>>> for i in array:
...    del i[0], i[-1]
>>> array
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, so stupid. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MickeyMahoney If it helped you may consider accepting :)

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(array)
array[1:3, 1:3]
```

return

```
array([[5, 6],
       [8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, with `<list>.pop`:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 1],
         [4, 5, 6, 4],
         [7, 8, 9, 7], 
         [7, 8, 9, 7]]

for i in range(len(array)): # range(len(<list>)) converts 'i' to the list inedx number.
    array[i].pop(0)
    array[i].pop(-1)
```

To answer your question,

`.remove` removes the first matching value, not a specific index. Where as `.pop` removes the it by the index.

Hope this helps!